# count how many times the webpage has been printed

Tags: javascript, printing

I want to put a maximum count when printing a receipt which was pulled from an sql via php. The receipt is displayed as a web page with window.print() function on body onload. Is this possible? To count how many times the button 'print' has been clicked and then disable the print dialog once the maximum print has been reached.

Comment: If you have a separate page, then you can limit the requests. But with JavaScript, IMO I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar, I actually have a separate page for printing, my "print-invoice.php", which has the onload=window.print().

Comment: Use a server side command using session and make sure it doesn't get loaded after 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this might help you.
You can use JQuery and Ajax request to count the number of times 'Ctrl+P' is pressed.

```
jQuery(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
        return false;
    }
});
```